# How can I print the line numbers of gedit?

Tags: printing, gedit, source-code

I want to print the line numbers along with c source-code in the text editor "Gedit". I am tired to look all day at the display.

Thank you for any time or effort.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open the *Print...* menu from the *File* tab

   [image: screenshoot_1]
2. Select the 3º tab called "Text Editor"
3. Click the second option "Print line numbers" so this checkbox remains *enabled*

   [image: screenshoot_2]

Now you can choice *Print Preview* and you will see the line numbers before print it:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

In the edit menu click on preferences and in the in the first tab "View" tick the check box labeled display line numbers

Comment: I can see the line numbers in gedit but when I print the document there is no line numbers